# Reading url from a specific list then downloading one by one

Tags: python

I have the following code :

```
for url in open('archive.txt'):
name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[+1]
browser.get(url)
```

My problem is that in "archive.txt" I have some link which I want to open, for downloading. But I want to open one by one. Open the first link, download and then move to the next link from the "archive.txt" and so on. But the code seems to not work properly: it opens the last link from the "archive.txt", passes it to youtube-dl and after it finished downloading, the script stops. It does not go to another link from the list. This is what the list looks like:

https://somesite.com/cp/modules/view/id/1

https://somesite.com/cp/modules/view/id/2

https://somesite.com/cp/modules/view/id/3

https://somesite.com/cp/modules/view/id/4

Thanks!

Comment: The links are only examples.I want to open links from a text file then downloading one by one. Read first link from the text file, downloading then go to the next one and  so on. Thank you!

Comment: @Nils: Don't fix the indentation of the code in the question if exactly that might be the problem.

Comment: Ohh ups, my bad. .Sorry for that.

Comment: Still does not work. Even with the code provided by user cocool97. Can anyone provide me a solution here ?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python is an indentation-sensitive language. You have to indent your code to put it into loops. Your code should look like the following :

```
for url in open('archive.txt'):
     name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[+1]
     browser.get(url)
```

The problem you have is is that the `for url in open('archive.txt'):` instruction loops and doesn't execute anything, until the last link. This is why you don't have anything except the last one.

Comment: I did like you told me but it does the same thing: reading the last link from the file and after open and finish downloading that one, the script stop and does not reading another link. Thanks!